# SSIS package for - stored proc multiple result set to multiple worksheets of an excel file

Tags: excel, ssis, procedure

I want a stored proc which results multiple result set and i ant to put the resultset in different sheet of an excel file.
i googled and got info of writing a script component which results in multiple result set but how do i map to different sheets of an excel

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32151/How-to-Use-a-Multi-Result-Set-Stored-Procedure-in

or Is there any other way to do it?? by using for loop container?? Please help.

Comment: Does the data on each sheet have the same columns? It's difficult to do sheet type operations without a script component. You aren't doing this to get around the 64,000 row limit are you?

Comment: no they are different columns.. and data from different tables..no this is not to limit the rows.. the result sets from stored procedure are different.. this is a client requirement to put the data in different sheets.. I have written the script component to give different result set set. But not able to map to different sheets of an excel. I want to know how will you map the different out put to different worksheet of an excel..

Comment: Have you added any Excel destinations yet? Excel destinations should let you define the sheet. If your SP has 5 recordsets, the code you linked to should allow you to build a script source with 5 outputs. Drop on 5 Excel destinations, configure each destination to point at the correct sheet, then join the script source outputs to the Excel inputs. Try that

Comment: This solution is an 'explicit' solution. For every sheet you need to write script, have an excel destination, and have the data flow explicitly set up. Have you considered populating the Excel file from within Excel using VBA? Is this an option? This means a user can refresh it whenever they like.

Comment: I am new to SSIS.. so may be the questions i am asking is basic,, Yes the script has many output.. I have used destination as excel.. But how do i specify that it should go to first sheet of an excel and second output to second sheet of excel. We just give the excel location and excel name in the path.. how do we specify work sheet name.. Thats where i am stuck.

Comment: Nick, your 3rd comment is not clear for me. Do we need to write script to write to excel destination and moreover am not familiar with VBA.